# Load GIF from documents directory and convert it to data

Tags: swift, path, gif, nsdocumentdirectory

```
 guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: bundleURL) else {
            print("Cannot turn image named \"\(gifNamed)\" into NSData")
            return nil

        }
```

I want to use GIF path in documents directory and extract the data from it not with `bundleUrl` but with GIF path in : `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5615E8E1-F120-4171-A7CE-B2A9F2E8FC19/Documents/test.gif`

Comment: what is `bundleURL`?

Comment: it's like : bundleURL = Bundle.main
            .url(forResource: gifNamed, withExtension: "gif")

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to get data from gif that is located in you app's Documents directory. Your code may look like that:

```
func getDataOf(gifNamed: String) -> Data? {
    // Get url of Documents directory
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    guard let documentsDirectory = paths.first else { return nil }

    // Get url of your gif
    guard let gifURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(gifNamed) else { return nil }

    // Extract the data of your gif
    var data: Data?
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: bundleURL)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return data
}
```

Comment: UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/F5111110-D632-495D-8F80-E50B3FE45D2A/Documents/testt.gif, NSUnderlyingError=0x283048000 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Comment: Does your gif exist there?

Comment: Maybe the problem in typo: your log says that your are looking for testt.gif? Maybe you wanted test.gif?

Comment: when I download my iPhone container I find my gif images there but I can't access them it always says the path is nil

Comment: So are they the part of Bundle? I mean, can you see them inside your xcode project? Or you download them in the runtime?

Comment: they are not part of bundle , when I put gif inside Xcode project and use bundle the gif is correct but I don't want to use a gif inside my Xcode project , I am using a custom gif then I save that gif inside the tmp directory , after that I move the file from the tmp directory to the documents directory , but when I use my code or your code above to retrieve the gif path from the directory it says it doesn't exist

Comment: Could you please provide the code you use to save a gif?

Comment: Also the code you use to move it